# Edit polygon path event for multipath polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck on telling an edit event which path of my polygon I have edited. I need to know this because I post the polygon's coordinates to a server and need to be able to tell it which path of the polygon I changed.

Originally, my polygons were all single path polygons, and all I had to pass to my editPolygon() method was the index of the edited vertex (which gets passed as the first parameter automatically). However, I now need to also pass the polygon path's index that I am editing. Because my polygons can have multiple paths, I need to be able to say "edit path 1 and update that part".

The below code is my attempt to add the pathIndex as a parameter, but its value does not carry into the anonymous function. It also appears that the 2nd parameter of the function is automatically set as the LatLng object of the edited vertex. I can see I need to access the polygon's paths in the function, but the scope won't allow it.

```
var pathIndex = polygon.getPaths().getAt(thisIndex);
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function(editIndex) {
            editPolygon(editIndex, pathIndex);
        });
```

Any ideas on how to tell which path of a multipath polygon you are editing? If there is functionality to tell you which vertex in a path you changed, shouldn't there be a way to tell you which path in the polygon changed as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution, but it may not be the most elegant.

When I create each path in the polygon, I set a property for the index within that polygon. For example:

```
polygonPath.pathIndex = indexOfPathInPolygon;
```

It's now part of that MVCArray.

Now I just need to set up the event handler normally:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygonPath, 'set_at', editPolygon);
```

And when editPolygon() is called, I can access that index because 'this' references the MVCArray I edited:

```
function editPolygon(editIndex) {
    var editedPath = myPolygon.getPaths.getAt(this.pathIndex);

}
```